# resuming activity nullpointer exception

Tags: android, json, android-viewpager

I have an activity that has a view pager and loads it's images from a JSON ( and so, several fragments ).
When I do some kind of external activity like start a phonecall or see a website ( via my aplication ), when this activity resumes it gives me a null pointer exception.

```
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagefromurl/com.example.imagefromurl.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2373)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2425)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at com.example.imagefromurl.FragmentOne.onCreateView(FragmentOne.java:28)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1901)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:567)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1167)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5132)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2346)
10-24 19:36:56.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18567):    ... 11 more
```

Is the any way that I can solve this?

Line 28: sUrl = activity.urlProfile.toString();

translation - on main activity I run the AsynkTask and I get this string sUrl . then on the fragment I cast the activity and get the string ( probably you would figure that by yourselves but it doesnt hurt to describe it all )

Comment: FragmentOne.java - line 28, this is the cause. There is an object which is a null

Comment: The problem is caused by an exception at line 28, class FragmentOne, post your code.

Comment: yeah sorry - I've been programing for 20 hours straight now so I totally forgot that LOOL 

Edited my post!

Answer (score 0):

1. Either the fragment has lost the instance of that `activity`, so the field `activity` is null.
2. Or the the field inside the activity `urlProfile` is null.
3. Or you casted your activity into a wrong activity, usually you get the activity with getActivity() or you catch that from the parameters.

But the main problem is, that you try to call toString() on a `null` which causes the exception. Try to catch it with

```
if(activity != null && activity.urlProfile != null) {
   sUrl = activity.urlProfile.toString();
} else {
   // do something different when those objects are null
}
```

Comment: Will try and five a feedback ! 

Genious answer - Seeing like that the problem is so simple that it's a shame I didn't find the answer myself !!

thanks !